# WordPress - Where would I put custom classes and database calls?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress CMS site and I want to add my own classes that make my own calls tot he WordPress database.  Where would be the ideal place to put these so they are easily accessible?  I'm guessing it would go either in wp-content or wp-includes but I don't know which.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put them in your template folder, in the functions.php file.

Comment: It's gonna get crowded in there with all my custom post types and taxonomies.  :)  Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you could create a 'classes.php' file and include it in your functions.php file.

Comment: Even better: create it as a plugin, which is going to be easier to re-use on other projects, and can be organized into its own folder.